# In swift: how to add tab bar icons to a regular ViewController storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I would like to add two tab bar icons (table view and collection view), as shown in the first figure below, to a regular ViewController storyboard (as shown in the second figure).

[image: Tab bar icons]

[image: regular ViewController]

I have tried to embed the ViewController in the TabBarController (Editor -> Embed in -> Tab Bar Controller), but it seems to me that xcode only allows me to add one icon (Tab Bar Item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one view controller per tab in the storyboard, then connect the tab view controller to those controllers using "relationship segue", "view controllers" (ctrl-drag from tab view controller to destination controllers, then select that).

In each controller you then can click the tab item and set an image, in attributes.

Answer (score 1):

add tab bar item to the view controller u want to add in tab bar controller. and then control drag from tab bar view controller and the make "relationship segue as "view controllers"..